# C# ASP.NET - date textbox using textmode=datetimelocal not saving date selection into SQL Server database, and not getting date from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I'm adding date textbox using `textmode=datetimelocal` but it's not saving date selection into the SQL Server database after click on update button.

I'm not getting date or cannot fetch date from SQL Server database after page load (by using development server mode). When I'm testing the code on my localhost, the date textbox is working perfectly (can store the selection date and can fetch the date into textbox).

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TargetDate" runat="server" TextMode="DateTimeLocal" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateBtn_Click"/>
```

C#

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {
        :
        :
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (sdr.Read())
        { 
            txtDate.Text = sdr["TargetDate"].ToString();
        }
```

```
protected void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form[TargetDate.UniqueID]);
    

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    try
    {
         cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table SET TargetDate=@TargetDate WHERE CaseID=@CaseID", con);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetDate", targetDate);

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         string message = "You have updated case detail.";
         string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
         script += message;
         script += "')};";

         ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);

         Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2");
         Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         string message = "Please try again";
         string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
         script += message;
         script += "')};";
         ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FailedMessage", script, true);
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
     }
}

    
Please anyone help me. P/s: I already correct my typing error.
```

Comment: The code is full of errors. The first three lines are parsing the input into a date, then formatting it into a string then back into a date. And finally not using that at all, passing an undefined string `stringDate` to a query that expects a CaseID. If the name `stringDate` is any indication, that variable doesn't contain a DateTime at all

Comment: What is `TargetDate`? The ASP code contains a field named `txtDate`, not `TargetDate`

Comment: Can you guys help me to correct the code?

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake. The code got typing error before. I already updated the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing in the CaseId here:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table SET Date=@Date WHERE CaseID=@CaseID", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", stringDate);
```

Comment: That's only one of the problems. Where did `stringDate` come from and what does it contain?